# Testing HTTP parameter without sending or receiving HTTP requests

Tags: post, get, phpunit

I am testing a function using PHPUnit, the function checks if there are any GET POST parameters set. 
If Set it returns it otherwise returns null. I have no idea how can i test it as i am not setting any http request. The function is as follows,

```
 public static function getURIParameter($param, $defaultValue=null) {
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$param]) && is_array($_REQUEST[$param]))
        return $_REQUEST[$param];
    else
        return isset($_REQUEST[$param]) ? trim($_REQUEST[$param]) : $defaultValue;
}
```

And this is my test function, with some psuedo kind of code.

```
     public function testGetURIParameter()
{   
    $_POST['parameter'] = true; // is something like that possible?
    $this->assertSame('POST', Core::getURIParameter('parameter'));

}
```

Can anyone tell me how can i test this function?

Comment: Look into Mock Objects to fake what you want returned to test functionality.  https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Answer (score 0):

First, you should devide you code into logic and transport layer. Then use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern to inject transport into logic:

```
<?php

interface TransportInterface {

    public function request($url, $params, $method);

}

class Logic {

    public function __construct(TransportInterface $transport) {
        $this->transport = $transport;
    }
}
```

You should create 2 implementations of TransportInterface - real one (cUrl) and stub one (with empty method) to use it in test env.

In tests you [create mock object](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) for `StubTransport`, provide [expectations](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.examples.SubjectTest.php) and inject it into `Logic` class.